# What's the fastest way to teleport and reach to Andrius, Dominator of Wolves weekly boss?

Tags: genshin-impact

Let's assume I'm in Lyiue or anywhere else far away from my intended target. Not in Monstadt region, for sure. I open the map, and scroll to Andrius, Dominator of Wolves weekly boss challenge.

There are several teleporters I can pick. None of them are right by the boss.

Which route is the fastest? Assume I have no special characters with skills that help movement, or any equipment, synergy, consumable, or gadget.

Also, I can't bunny hop.

Comment: climbing the mountains seems fastest (using teleport nearest to boss icon), though you need to climb mountain from the side - hills will be lower so less stamina wasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good video showing how long it would take depending on where you come from.

Fastest way apparently is via teleporting to Cecilia Garden then going down to Andrius.

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2GWb45yzkI)